# Pass a this.property to ObjectDataSource

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

A user control contains a ListView, ObjectDataSource and a CustomerID property, is there a way to pass CustomerID to ObjectDataSource.

it seems ControlParameter does not fix the problem.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ControlParameter must be used for to get a parameter from a Control. To get a parameter from a property you have to get it from code behind:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource OnSelecting="OdsOnSelecting" .... >
   <SelectParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" />
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:objectDataSource>

protected void OdsOnSelecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e) {
    e.InputParameters["CustomerID"] = CustemerID;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Respond to this event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.objectcreating.aspx

Comment: the event to handle is 'Selecting'

Comment: @Onof You are correct sir, not sure how I managed to misread the question like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an attribute/property for the usercontrol in question, THEN do what is mentioned in the two post before this one...